# Make a Group Bar Chart after nesting data in D3 using CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, bar-chart

I am not really familiar with D3 and I am struggling with the concept of creating a group bar chart after I nested the specific data. The grouped bar chart I am trying to create essentially should look this. The cluster of bars that are separated should indicate the residence hall and each color bar would indicate the school years of the amount of students in the residence hall. My issue is how would I get the value within the nested data to essentially be used as the height of a bar of the student's school year, how would I go around dividing the data by residence hall, and if you notice my console outputs only that school years that have a value, it doesn't output a value of 0 if the school year is not in the residence hall. I am just struggling to understand D3 and i want to know how to use the nested data to create the grouped bar graph.

This is just a general overview of how I want the bar chart to look. The values will obviously be different, just a general SketchUp.
[image: student grouped bar chart]

This is the console output of the data after using d3.nest(). If you notice, there isn't a key of "Sophomore" showing value 0. I do not know if that makes a difference when outputting into the graph.

```
0:
key: "Davis Hall"
    values: Array(3)
         0: {key: "Freshman", value: 1}
         1: {key: "Junior", value: 2}
         2: {key: "Senior", value: 2}
         length: 3
     __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
1:
key: "Jameson Hall"
   values: Array(3)
       0: {key: "Sophomore", value: 1}
       1: {key: "Junior", value: 3}
       2: {key: "Senior", value: 1}
       length: 3
   __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Below is how I nested my CSV data using D3.Nest and I used the count

```
d3.csv("./data/studentresidences.csv", function(data){
    var studentBuildings = d3.nest()
        .key(function(r) { return r.Residence; })
        .key(function(s) { return s.Schoolyear; })
        .rollup(function(a) { return a.length; })
        .entries(data)
        console.log(studentBuildings);
});
```

This is the CSV

```
Name, Residence, ID, Schoolyear, Major
Bill Thornton, Jameson Hall, 11123, Sophomore, Mathematics
Savannah Lipscombe, Davis Hall, 11231, Freshman, Biology
Jay Price, Jameson Hall, 12222, Senior, Business
Hassan Abdullah, Jameson Hall, 11111, Junior, Mechanical Engineering
Jo Park, Davis Hall, 22123, Junior, Political Science
Arnold Allen, Jameson Hall, 12314, Junior, Psychology
Anthony Daniels, Davis Hall,15125, Senior, Aerospace Engineering
Josephine Alvarez, Davis Hall,11512, Junior, Chemistry
Cynthia Blackman, Davis Hall,66142, Senior, Computer Science
Sophie Aspen, Jameson Hall,111221, Junior, English
```

Comment: Why did you delete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564842/d3-stacked-bar-chart-only-use-certain-columns-csv-counting-distinct-elemen/64570085#64570085) from yesterday? Since you asked for a stacked bar chart, and now for a grouped one, it looks like you weren't satisfied with the direction - but deleting a question blocks other people from gaining from that as well

Comment: my bad, i honestly thought i was supposed to do a stacked bar graph, turns out I needed a grouped one.

Comment: No problem, thanks for reopening it. Now, what have you tried so far? Your current rollup gives the number of majors, but not the unique number - or do you not need that anymore?

Comment: so in this case, the major is not needed anymore, but rather i need the total number of freshman, sophomores, etc in the bar graph. the current rollup should give that

Comment: All right, and what have you tried so far? Do you have an attempt you can share with us? Maybe a tutorial or online example that did or didn't work?

Comment: ive been trying to understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302958/d3-accessing-nested-data-in-grouped-bar-chart/35443636

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. Your start was good, but you need to have two x-axes. One divides the total domain up into equal spots per residence, and one that takes that residence area and divides it per year.

You can easily use `x.bandwidth()` to get the size of that area.

```js
const dataString = `Name, Residence, ID, Schoolyear, Major
Bill Thornton, Davis Hall, 11123, Sophomore, Mathematics
Savannah Lipscombe, Jameson Hall, 11231, Freshman, Biology
Jay Price, Davis Hall, 12222, Senior, Business
Hassan Abdullah, Arthur Hall, 11111, Junior, Mechanical Engineering
John Doe, Arthur Hall, 11112, Junior, Mechanical Engineering
Jo Park, Reed Hall, 22123, Freshman, Political Science`.replace(/, /g, ",");

const unique = array => array.filter((v, i) => array.indexOf(v) === i);

const data = d3.csvParse(dataString);
const years = unique(data.map(d => d.Schoolyear));

var groupedData = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.Residence)
  .key(d => d.Schoolyear)
  .rollup(v => v.length)
  .entries(data)
console.log(groupedData);

const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 35,
    left: 35,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  // The residences
  .domain(groupedData.map(d => d.key))
  .padding(0.1);

const subX = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .domain(years)
  .padding(0.05);

// Calculate the nested max
const max = d3.max(
  groupedData,
  d => d3.max(d.values, e => e.value)
);
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, max])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["steelblue", "darkorange", "lightblue"])
  .domain(years);

const xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .attr("class", "x-axis")

const yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .attr("class", "y-axis")

svg.selectAll(".y-axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(null, "s"))

const bargroups = svg.selectAll("g.bargroup")
  .data(groupedData, d => d.key)

bargroups.exit().remove()

const bars = bargroups.enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("bargroup", true)
  .merge(bargroups)
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.key)}, 0)`)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d.values, e => e.key);

bars.exit().remove()

bars.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", subX.bandwidth())
  .merge(bars)
  .attr("x", d => subX(d.key))
  .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
  .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
  .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))

// Draw the main axis labels
xAxis
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(24));

// For every tick, add the year labels
xAxis.selectAll(".tick")
  .each(function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .selectAll(".year-tick")
      .data(years)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .classed("year-tick", true)
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", (d, i) => i % 2 === 0 ? 3 : 12)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("x", d => subX(d) - (x.bandwidth() / 2))
      .attr("dx", d => subX.bandwidth() / 2)
      .text(d => d);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: how can i possibly make it look like this example where you have the name of the year underneath each associating bar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812922/grouped-category-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-d3

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just add text nodes to each tick, copy the style from the main tick, and position them using the secondary x-axis